# How to write in a textbox on a website and submit

Tags: python

I'm trying to get to know my way around web-scraping with Python. I am currently attempting to input string into a textbox on a website (I am using https://test4python.sarahah.com/)

So I have found the text box using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
r = get('https://test4python.sarahah.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
findtextbox = soup.find('textarea',id='Text')
```

But now that I have done this, I am struggling to understand how I input string. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you cant do it with requests and bs4, you have to use seleium library for this

Comment: I can use any library I just want to know how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link to [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) and you will need chromedriver, download chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and place it in same folder as your script or add it in `PATH`.

This is a simple example :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://test4python.sarahah.com/")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea").send_keys("This is the input text which is inputed.")
```

Comment: my pleasure : )